# How to make a Vmware virtual machine if you have a vmdk file

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-player

I just got a vmdk file from a Windows Xp hot cloned system which i want to run on vmplayer. How can i generate the .vmx file ? I'm on Windows XP sp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [EasyVMX](http://www.easyvmx.com/easyvmx.shtml) in the past.

If you have a vmx file then you can just copy it and edit it in notepad or similar - some of the options are obvious but others need a bit of work to find out what is allowable.

(So if you accept the default name for the hard disk, it is easy to change the name of the disk file to your existing file.)

Comment: i do not have a vmx file

Comment: Then create a new virtual machine, copy the vmx file from that (and optionally clean up by deleting the new machine).